# Не понимаю, что делает .astype() в numpy - она округляет числа?

Tags: python, numpy

Не понимаю, что делает .astype() - она округляет числа? 
И второй вопрос как следствие первого: подскажите, как изменить функцию с lambda, чтобы изменить массив нужным образом.
Сейчас:

```
[[ 0.69053728]
 [ 2.7581594 ]
 [-5.50454002]]

A = lambda x: (x >= 1).astype(float)
```

Получаю на выходе:

```
[[ 0]
 [ 1]
 [ 0]]
```

Как сделать, чтобы получить:

```
[[ 0]
 [ 1]
 [-1]]
```

Т.е. отрицательные числа меньше -1 должны превращаться в -1.

Comment: `numpy` (если речь о нём) как бы не совсем питон. Вот ссылка [numpy.ndarray.astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype)

Comment: А во что должны превращаться отрицательные числа больше -1?

Comment: Те числа, которые больше -1 но меньше 1 превращаются в ноль

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NDArray.astype(type)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) возвращает копию массива преобразованного к указанному типу:

```
In [383]: (a >= 1)
Out[383]:
array([[False],
       [ True],
       [False]])

In [384]: (a >= 1).astype(float)
Out[384]:
array([[0.],
       [1.],
       [0.]])
```

---

Ответ на второй вопрос:

используйте метод [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [390]: res = np.where(a < -1, -1, np.where(a >= 1, 1, 0))

In [391]: res
Out[391]:
array([[ 0],
       [ 1],
       [-1]])
```